# JavaScript: Pull a specific string inside a string

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript. I am a little bit confused of how can I pull a specific string inside a string. To make it clearer, I want to remove the `my` and `are delicious.` in the examples below and only return the text in between the two. For as long as possible, no jQuery is required.

`'my cheesecakes are delicious.'`
`'cheesecakes'`

`'my salad and sandwiches are delicious.'`
`'salad and sandwiches'`

`'my tunas are delicious.'`
`'tunas'`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.indexOf()` and `.substr()` methods

```
var text = 'my cheesecakes are delicious.';

var from = text.indexOf('my');

var to = text.indexOf('are delicious.')

var final = text.substr(from + 'my'.length, to - 'my'.length);

final = final.trim(); // cut spaces before and after string

console.log(final);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've tried your answer and it's finally working, thank you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace()` method to replace one substring with another. In this example, I'm first replacing the leading "my" with "" (empty string) and the trailing "are delicious." with "" (empty string). For more information on the "^" and "$" modifiers, look into [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```
var s = 'my salad and sandwiches are delicious.'; // example
var y = s.replace( /^my /, '' ).replace( /are delicious\.$/, '' );
alert( y );
```

Comment: Please expand on your answer and break it down piece by piece for the person asking the question. The code solution on its own doesn't little to help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

You can use `map` function to loop through the elements of the array and replace all the required values. The trim function will ensure that there are no trailing white spaces at both the edges of the string.

```js
var testcases = ['my cheesecakes are delicious.', 'cheesecakes',
  'my salad and sandwiches are delicious.', 'salad and sandwiches',
  'my tunas are delicious.', 'tunas'
];

testcases = testcases.map(function(x) {
  return x.replace("my", "").replace("are delicious.", "").trim();
})
console.log(testcases);
```

```css
.as-console {
  height: 100%
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the unwanted parts with one replace.

```js
var strings = ['my cheesecakes are delicious.', 'my salad and sandwiches are delicious.', 'my tunas are delicious.', 'foo'];

console.log(strings.map(function (s) {
    return s.replace(/my\s+|\s+are\sdelicious\./g, '');
}));
```

Proposal with matching the inner part.

```js
var strings = ['my cheesecakes are delicious.', 'my salad and sandwiches are delicious.', 'my tunas are delicious.', 'foo'];

console.log(strings.map(function (s) {
    return (s.match(/^my (.*) are delicious\.$/) || [,''])[1];
}));
```